# How to implement code for get the xml data and save inot xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to implement code for below xml file

```
<root>
  <keys>
    <key>
      <Question>Is the color of the car</Question>
      <Ans>black?</Ans>
    </key>
    <key>
      <Question>Is the color of the car</Question>
      <Ans>black?</Ans>
    </key>
    <key>
      <Question>Is the news paper </Question>
      <Ans>wallstreet?</Ans>
    </key>
    <key>
      <Question>fragrance odor</Question>
      <Ans>Lavendor?</Ans>
    </key>
    <key>
      <Question>Is the baggage collector available</Question>
      <Ans></Ans>
    </key>
  </keys>
</root>
```

Display on the screen as:

List form
Is the color of the car black? Check box
Is the baggage collector available? Check box

If the check box is checked - Yes otherwise value is no.

On save button: we need to save it into a xml file. So any one help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok - first of all you have accepted 1 of 25 answers on Stack Overflow (but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that 24 questions received an answer which did not suit you). Second - what the ?!##! are you talking about? Please re-word your question so that humans can understand it :>. You have not posted any xml, you posted a bunch of random questions about cars, colors, and newspapers??!

Comment: <root>
<keys>
<key>
<Question>Is the color of the car</Question>
<Ans>black?</msg>
</key>
<key>
<Question>Is the color of the car</Question>
<Ans>black?</Ans>
</key>
<key>
<Question>Is the news paper </Question>
<Ans>wallstreet?</Ans>
</key>
<key>
<Question>fragrance odor</Question>
<Ans>Lavendor?</Ans>
</key>
<key>
<Question>Is the baggage collector available</Question>
<Ans></Ans>
</key>
</keys>
</root>
This is what I found while editing.Before posting question you must make sure whether it is in proper format or not.What exactly do you want? do you want to form and XML or parse this XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your question it appears you want to fetch contents of XML. For that you need to parse the XML. Create an XMLClass.java

```
public class XMLfunctions {

public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;

}

/** Returns element value
  * @param elem element (it is XML tag)
  * @return Element value otherwise empty String
  */
 public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node kid;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return kid.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 public static String getXML(int s, int y){  
        String line = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String link = "//YOUR URL HERE" add LIMITS IF ANY
                 for ex: String link = "www.ab.com/index.php?action=gq&start="+s+"&limit="+y;
// it will give you values from 1 to 10 or 1 to 50 whatever you mention         
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(link);

            System.out.println("Httppost="+httpPost);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            System.out.println("HttpEntity="+httpEntity);

            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            System.out.println("Line="+line);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }

        return line;

}
```

Then in other class call this getXML function

declare int s and int y with some value

```
   String xmls = XMLfunctions2.getXML(loginid);    

    Document docs = XMLfunctions2.XMLfromString(xmls);
    NodeList node = docs.getElementsByTagName("start");

for (int i = 0; i < node.getLength(); i++) {    

        org.w3c.dom.Element e = (org.w3c.dom.Element)node.item(i);
        if(i==0)

        {
            quest= XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "Question");
            ans=XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "Answer");
            key=XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "key");

        }
```

}